# With Unix find(1), how do I find files in one tree newer than counterparts in another tree?

Tags: unix, find

Let's say I have two directory structures:

```
/var/www/site1.prod
/var/www/site1.test
```

I want to use [find(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) to see the files that are newer in `/var/www/site1.test` than their counterparts in `/var/www/site1.prod`.

Can I do this with [find(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find), and if so, how?

Comment: retitle: 'find(1) files newer than others' at the very least, please

Comment: +1 interesting. Though likely to be closed as this is more related to sysadmining than to programming. Me, I don't separate them as neatly.

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza: I would count shell scripting as programming :)

Comment: I did say that _I_ wouldn't close it. But as far as I've seen in other questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't do it with find alone, but you can do something like

```
$ cd /var/www/site1.test
$ files=`find .`
$ for $f in $files; do
     if [ $f -nt /var/www/site1.prod/$f ]; then echo "$f changed!"; fi;
  done
```

Comment: minor modifications:

for f in $files; do
  if [ $f -nt /var/www/site1.prod/$f ]; then echo "$f changed"; fi;
done

Comment: This will break for filenames containing blanks, and break for a large number of files on certain (ba)shes.

Comment: Warning: This won't tell you if a new file was created in /var/www/site1.prod and not in /var/www/site1.test -- which may be acceptable.

Comment: This isn't the first shell script I've seen on SO that conveniently forgets that file names may contain blanks.

Answer (score 8):

You also could use rsync -n

rsync -av -n /var/www/site1.test /var/www/site1.prod

should do it.

Answer (score 4):

**Using find**,

```
cd /var/www/site1.test
find . -type f -print | while read file ; do
  [ "$file" -nt /var/www/site1.prod/"$file" ] && echo "File '$file' changed"
done
```

**This will work with filenames containing blanks, as well as work for a large volume of files.**

To distinguish between modified and missing files, as per Eddie's comments,

```
cd /var/www/site1.test
find . -type f -print | while read file ; do
  [ "$file" -nt /var/www/site1.prod/"$file" ] && reason=changed
  [ \! -e /var/www/site1.prod/"$file" ] && reason=created
  [ -n "$reason" ] && echo "$file $reason"
done
```

Comment: Warning: Like the solution you are correcting, this won't tell you if a new file was created in /var/www/site1.prod and not in /var/www/site1.test -- which may be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the -fprintf option you should be able to create two finds that output into two files that list the files name and modification time.  You should then be able to just diff the two files to see what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you specifically asked for newer, but I think it's always good to know all your options.

I would use diff -ur dir1 dir2.

Maybe the timestamp changed, maybe it didn't, but that doesn't necessarily tell you if the contents are the same. Diff will tell you if the contents changed. If you really don't want to see the contents use diff -rq to just see the files that changed.

Comment: That's if you are using a version of diff that supports the "-q" option.